# Space between table caption and caption text

Tags: captions

At the moment, I have the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang, labelsep=quad}
```

This creates a nice space between the table caption and the caption text. However, I would also like to add a colon after the table number, and at the same time have the separation between the colon and the caption text. As far as I know, `\captionsetup` only allows one attribute for labelsep. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. The `caption` package provides the command `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator` to define your own caption label separator.

So, declaring

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{mysep}{:\quad}
```

and using

```
\captionsetup{format=hang, labelsep=mysep}
```

you can obtain what you want.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{mysep}{:\quad}
\captionsetup{format=hang, labelsep=mysep}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \hline
    hello \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user81520 You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know captions of tables go above the table. 
If you do this, you can just add a little space to the line separator `\\` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
   \centering
   \caption{A table} %captions go atop of a table
  \begin{tabular}{c}
   \\[1pt]  %This is the important part
   \hline
    hello \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Hope this helps!